# Is it possible to use mTLS and API key authentication on the same custom domain, using API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've configured my API gateway to work with mTLS authentication and it’s working fine.

Now, I need to add a new API gateway with API Key authentication on the same custom domain but can’t find a way to do it.

Is there any way to define the authentication method for a specific API gateway under the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutual TLS (mTLS) is configured at the [custom domain level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-mutual-tls.html#rest-api-mutual-tls-configure) in API Gateway. This means that when mTLS is enabled for a custom domain, it applies to *all APIs* under that domain.

If you want to use API Key authentication for a specific API, you need to use a different custom domain.

Comment: Thank you @Ermiya, this is what i tought and you confirmed it, hope to see in future a way to specify the Authentication method on API level :/